# Forwarding "/blog" to a wordpress installation when using Google App Engine standard environment

Tags: python, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, reverse-proxy

I have a webapp running on Python2.7 in Google App Engine's standard environment.

We'd like to host a wordpress blog for the app available at `/blog` - with nginx this would be quite easy using it as a reverse-proxy, but since we have no control over the routing for the google app engine project, I'm not sure of the best way to implement this.

For SEO reasons, we'd like to avoid a `blog.example.com` subdomain.

Does anyone have any experience of doing something similar?

Comment: Are you planning to host the blog on App Engine (as a separate service) as well? Or elsewhere?

Comment: WordPress will be hosted completely separately - outside of app engine

Answer (score 1):

Setup wordpress in App Engine by following these instructions, but edit the service name in the `app.yaml` so that it is a separate microservice:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/php72/wordpress

Then setup `dispatch.yaml` to route traffic to it:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately WordPress won't be hosted on app engine, however this gives me an idea. I could setup a service running a reverse proxy and use the dispatch.yaml to send blog requests to it.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be possible unless the Wordpress blog is deployed as a separate App Engine service [and dispatched accordingly](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml).

Comment: What about the option of deploying a reverse proxy as an App Engine service and using that to point to wordpress?